# decode Hexadecimal encoding in html

Tags: php, html

I have entities in html like:

```
&#xEA75; &#xE714; &#xE7CB; &#xE9D0; &#xE683;
```

Tried `htmlspecialchars_decode` and `html_entity_decode`, but still getting some rectangles. Any ideas how can I display normal letters instead of this hexadecimal stuff? Thanks in advance. Example in context:

```
<div class="name">
    <span data-obfuscation="gyned87c" class="firstname">&#xE9E5;&#xE8F9;&#xE9B0;&#xE856;&#xE714;&#xE7CB;&#xE9D0;</span>
    <span data-obfuscation="gyned87c"class="lastname">&#xE7D8;&#xE8F9;&#xE6C5;&#xE714;&#xE9D0;&#xE725;&#xE7CB;&#xE9D0;&#xE96D;&#xE8F9;</span>
</div>
<span class="number">02</span>
```

Comment: have you tried with the additional flags? for example: `html_entity_decode($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')`

Comment: Tried, same result.

Comment: Are they used in cotext of normal sentece next to latin chars?

Comment: Are you judging by the rendering your web browser produces? If so, are you sure the font used for such rendering really contains glyphs for those symbols?

Comment: Added html example

Comment: Of course you're getting rectangles. There are no standard glyphs for that block of Unicode.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams so it is possible to convert them to normal letters?

Comment: ... Only if you know how they were encoded in the first place...